# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Tags: python, database, flask, model, relationship

I'm creating a blog post function for a social media website. However, when I clicked the post button to post a blog, the website doesn't redirect me to the template I put in while showing an error in my terminal: 'AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'.

Looking at the traceback, I saw that there are something to do with the relationship I did between the User and the BlogPost models.

**Here is the code for my models(or models.py):**

````
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin
from datetime import datetime

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)




class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    profile_image = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False, default='default_profile.jpg' ) 
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True) 
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    username = first_name + last_name
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    posts = db.relationship('BlogPost', backref='creator', lazy=True) 

    def __init__(self,email,first_name,last_name, password):    
        self.email = email
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Username: {self.username}"



class BlogPost(db.Model):

    users = db.relationship(User)

    blog_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False) #users.id  is taken from the tablename(users) and id in its table
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow) 
    problem_name = db.Column(db.String(140), nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, text, problem_name, user_id):
        self.text = text
        self.problem_name = problem_name
        self.user_id = user_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post ID: {self.post_id} -- Date:{self.date}---{self.problem_name}" ```
````

**Here is the code for my views(or views.py) of the posting blog:**

```
blog_posts = Blueprint('blog_posts',__name__)

@blog_posts.route('/create', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def create_post():
    form = BlogPostForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        blog_validated = BlogPost(problem_name=form.problem_name.data,
                                  text=form.text.data,
                                  user_id=current_user.id
                                  )
        db.session.add(blog_validated)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Blog Post Created')
        return redirect(url_for('core.index'))

    return render_template('create_post.html', form=form)
```

**And here is the code for the template create_post.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
<form method="POST" >
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.problem_name.label(class="form-control-label") }} {{ form.problem_name(class="form-group form-control") }}<br>
    {{ form.text.label }} {{ form.text(class="form-group form-control") }}<br>
    {{ form.problem_submit.label(class="btn btn-secondary")}}
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**Below is my full traceback:**
[image][image: Traceback.imagem.no1]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUZap.png): 
P/s. All the views and templates and codes work well using the User model. 
I'm a student and I'm creating a project. My computer science teacher can't help me so I'm really stuck. Please, please help. Thank you!

Comment: What is `home_user`?

Comment: Hi kpie! home_user is a variable that I created for another routes in users/views: 
`@users.route('/<username>')
def user_posts(username):
    page = request.args.get('page',1,type=int) 
    home_user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first_or_404 
blog_posts = BlogPost.query.filter_by(creator=home_user).order_by(BlogPost.date.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=5) 
    return render_template('user_blog_posts.html', blog_posts=blog_posts, home_user=home_user)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 93 in user_post you need to put parentheses on the end of the line that defines `home_user`.

```
@users.route('/<username>')
def user_posts(username):
     page = request.args.get('page',1,type=int)
     home_user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first_or_404() # <= You're missing the ()
     blog_posts = BlogPost.query.filter_by(creator=home_user).order_by(BlogPost.date.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=5) return render_template('user_blog_posts.html', blog_posts=blog_posts, home_user=home_user)
```

Comment: It worked!!! The error no longer appeared in my terminal but when I click the post button at "create_post.html", it doesn't do anything. In my code, it should redirect the user to core.index, which will then redirect to an index HTML template. Could you also help me on this one? If you need more picture or code, I'm happy to send you. Thank you!!!

Comment: is `form.validate_on_submit()` false?

Comment: You'd probably be best to post a new question with your views.py and BlogPostForm() code.

Comment: Yes, the code behind form.validate_on_submit() doesnt' work. My page successfully show the create_post.html but didn't redirect to the core.index's index.html when I click the button.

Comment: Ok, I will post a new question. Thank you so much for helping me!!

Comment: when `validate_on_submit()` returns `True` the redirect should happen... I assume.

Comment: I just posted a separate question. Hopefully it would be easier for you to help me: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60784675/form-validate-on-submit-doesnt-worknothing-happen-when-i-submit-a-form]. And thank you so much for helping me!

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: This is a bad answer but I'm curious if it would work**

**:** O

On line 94 in user_post you need to call homeuser... `filter_by(creator=homeuser())` as opposed to `filter_by(creator=homeuser)`

Comment: Hi kpie, I'm very sorry but I'm struggling with a new problem and it would be really great if you could help me: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61520545/13097721 Thank you!